# Twitter Typeahead: Suggestion list goes away when ajax fetching result for new keyword

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-typeahead

I am using Twitter Typeahead (v0.11.1). I have configured an ajax call to get suggestion list upon typing each letter in textbox.

On entering every character an ajax call gets send and it brings results. If typed continuously in textbox then previous ajax calls are aborted and new ajax call is sent on pause of last character entered.

So, while this process if found some results after two characters and paused then it showing suggestion list. Now, if continue to type then exiting list goes away.

I would like to retain suggestion list for each ajax call till user not selected an item from it.

Below is the code used:

```
var typeahead_pre_written_xhr = null;
var helper_typeahead = $( "#input-box" ).typeahead({
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 0
},
{
  name: "Search Suggestions",
  display: ["title"],
  templates: {
    empty: function () {
        return '<div class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable">No matching helper comment found</div>';
    }
  },
  source: function (query, processSync, processAsync) {

    if( typeahead_pre_written_xhr !=  null ) {
      typeahead_pre_written_xhr.abort();
      typeahead_pre_written_xhr = null;
    }

    action_url = "suggestion_list";
    return typeahead_pre_written_xhr = $.ajax({ cache: false
      , url: action_url + query
      , type: 'POST'
      , data: { 'search': query }
      , dataType: 'json'
      , success: function (data)
      {
        return processAsync(data.res);
      }
    });
  }
}).bind("typeahead:selected", function(evt, item) {
   // do some stuff
});
```